# What does the '+=' operator do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, operators

The operator += is one that I have seen a lot in JavaScript and I have absolutely no idea what it does. Can someone simply define what it is and how I would use it in JavaScript? I found this example and I don't understand what is happening.

```
var message = "";
if (document.getElementById("x") == "") {
    message += "You must enter your last name."
}
```

Comment: You forgot close bracket at if statement

Comment: You would get an answer faster if you had just tested it yourself.

Comment: @JustinWood Yes Hello, I know that but I just want to know the theory behind it. I was just slightly confused.

Answer (score 3):

It is an assignment shortcut operator

`x += y` means `x = x + y`

See [the Shorthand Assignment operator table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators).

---

In javascript the `+` operator works on strings as well by concatenating them.. So in your case it will *add* to the `message` variable the string on the right side..

Answer (score 2):

It does the same thing as it does in `C` and `Java` and many other languages:

```
x += y;
```

is a shorthand for

```
x = x + y;
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. This is true (excluding some oddity cases), although a reference would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

In that case it means `message = message + "You must enter your last name."`. There might be some edge cases when variables are of different types and are automatically transformed to other types (which might produce unexpected results), but this does not seem to be the case.